# Is there a global option to adjust the default setting of tibbles that displays only 10 rows?

Tags: r, tibble

I often use tibbles and am quite satisfied with them. The only recurring issue that bothers me is having to constantly add `print(n = ...)` every time I want to view more than 10 rows. I'm aware that I could convert them to data frames using `as.data.frame()`, but I'd prefer to set a global print option, such as `print(n=100)`, for all tibbles until I decide to change it.

So far, what I've been doing is

##### using `print(n=....)`

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  print(n=20)
```

##### or using `as.data.frame()`

```
mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

##### or with a custom function (similar to data.table feature)

```
tar_head_tail <- function(data, nh = 15, nt = 15) {
  library(dplyr)
  library(crayon)
  
  x <- data %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    tibble::rownames_to_column("row_number") %>%
    head(n = nh)
  
  y <- data %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    tibble::rownames_to_column("row_number") %>%
    tail(n = nt)
  
  head_tail <- bind_rows(x, y) %>%
    tibble::column_to_rownames("row_number")
  
  # Apply color
  cat(green("Head:\n"))
  print(x)
  cat(red("\nTail:\n"))
  print(y)
  
  return(invisible(head_tail))
}

iris %>% 
  tar_head_tail()
```

How can we set a global print (such as print(n=20)) option for all tibbles until we decide to change it?

#### Update: What I expect:

When I do:

```
mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

it should show after setting global print(n=20):

```
# A tibble: 32 × 11
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21       6 160     110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2  21       6 160     110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3  22.8     4 108      93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4  21.4     6 258     110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5  18.7     8 360     175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 6  18.1     6 225     105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
 7  14.3     8 360     245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 8  24.4     4 147.     62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9  22.8     4 141.     95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
10  19.2     6 168.    123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
11  17.8     6 168.    123  3.92  3.44  18.9     1     0     4     4
12  16.4     8 276.    180  3.07  4.07  17.4     0     0     3     3
13  17.3     8 276.    180  3.07  3.73  17.6     0     0     3     3
14  15.2     8 276.    180  3.07  3.78  18       0     0     3     3
15  10.4     8 472     205  2.93  5.25  18.0     0     0     3     4
16  10.4     8 460     215  3     5.42  17.8     0     0     3     4
17  14.7     8 440     230  3.23  5.34  17.4     0     0     3     4
18  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08  2.2   19.5     1     1     4     1
19  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93  1.62  18.5     1     1     4     2
20  33.9     4  71.1    65  4.22  1.84  19.9     1     1     4     1
# ℹ 12 more rows
```

I want to avoid the additional line of `print(n=....)`, or `print()` etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dplyr` and other `tidyverse` packages import [`pillar`](https://pillar.r-lib.org/) for formatting printed output. The docs list various [options](https://pillar.r-lib.org/reference/pillar_options.html) to control how tibbles are printed.

For rows:

> `pillar.print_max`: Maximum number of rows printed, default: `20`. Set to `Inf` to always print all rows.

> `pillar.print_min`: Number of rows printed if the table has more than `print_max` rows, default: 10.

```r
options(
    "pillar.print_min" = 100
)

mtcars |>
    dplyr::as_tibble()
# prints all 32 rows of mtcars

iris |>
    dplyr::as_tibble()
# prints the first 100 rows of iris
```

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful, but not exactly what I mean. I will update to clarify!

Comment: @TarJae I have edited the answer  - if I understand your question (and maybe I don't!) you want `print_min` rather than `print_max`.

Comment: Yesss!!! Perfect that is it!